# How to use my actionsciprt 3.0 flash animation as a facebook application?

Tags: flash, facebook, animation, iframe

I tried to make a facebook app, but I failed. I have no idea how to use my flash content. I tried to make a new app with Fbook Developers, I uploaded the animation as an HTML file on my server, but it's not working. All i see is a blank page. Then I searched some codes, but none of them worked. This is my final code (which is still not working):

```
<fb:swf 
swfbgcolor="000000"
imgstyle="border-width:3px; border-color:white;"
swfsrc='http://fb.joma-sport.hu/valencia.swf'
imgsrc='http://fb.joma-sport.hu/valencia.jpg'
width='520' height='800' />
```

I want sg like this:
http://www.facebook.com/JomaSport.es?sk=app_186670448052790
(My page looks like this:
http://www.facebook.com/JomaSport.hu?sk=app_269610193049698)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What tutorial are you working off? <fb:swf is long-deprecated code, Facebook apps are just regular iFrames now and you can include flash content directlyq

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I'm new to all these stuff. Ok. Here's the thing: I made a flash animation and I wanted to use it as an application. I uploaded it to my server, saved the correct adress (http://fb.joma-sport.hu/valencia.swf) went to facebook developers, made a new app, and when it asked for page tab url i pasted the adress i saved before. but all i get is a blank page. then i googled how to use flash on fbook, and i found some codes (like the one above), but nothing happened. (the animation is working correctly, because i posted it on my pages wall as a regular post, and it's okay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got the answer. Several weeks ago a I googled " how to embed flash into html", and after a few tries I found a code, which is working. Honestly I don't remember which webpage was that, but this code is not made by me!!

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0"WIDTH=520 HEIGHT=700><PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="yourfile.swf"> <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=best> <PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE=transparent> <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#FFFFFF> <EMBED src="yourfile.swf<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="520" HEIGHT="700" id="yourfile.swf" ALIGN="">
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="yourfile.swf">
<PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
<PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#000000>
<EMBED src="yourfile.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#000000 WIDTH="520" HEIGHT="700" NAME="Yourfilename" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED></OBJECT>
```